# Can i traverse array in O(logn)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

Is there a way to access all the elements of array in time complexity of `O(log(n))` if it is not necessary to show output array in order.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you clarify that it is necessary to output the entire array, but not necessarily in the order they are stored in the array? Or, is it not necessary to show any output at all?

Comment: I guess what you actually wanted to ask, is how can I find an element in a sorted array without iterating the whole array, thus 0(log n). And the answer would be, divide and conquer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this because you need to at least visit all n items, if the array is sorted, you can find the right spot in O(log N).

Answer (score 3):

Can you eat 16 apples by just eating the first 4? The answer is no.

Comment: like your example

Answer (score 2):

No. There is `n` elements in the array, just to visit all of them you already spend O(n) time.